# Modify Default Namespace Prefix when doing XML Serialization for Response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serialization, xml-serialization

default XMLNamespace prefix set in the response is different for .Net Core and MVC
I am trying to mirror the behaviour to make it the same as MVC.

**I am not able to find how d1p1,d2p1 are set in .Net Core code. I believe they are default namespace prefixes. But i want it to a,b,c etc unlike d1p1,d2p1,d3p1,etc**

> I have not customised XMLFormatter in either project . I believe this
> is the way to fix but i cannot understand where i need to go looking

In Asp.Net Core web API :

```
<ReservationDetail xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.ReservationResponseModel">
    <Detail xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.ReservationModel">
        <d2p1:ActionItems xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.CommonModel"/>
        <d2p1:Association>
            <d2p1:ReservationAssociation>
                <d2p1:Requestor xmlns:d5p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.CommonModel">
                    <d5p1:ChannelName>NCC</d5p1:ChannelName>
                </d2p1:Requestor>
            </d2p1:ReservationAssociation>
        </d2p1:Association>
        <d2p1:Channel>NCC</d2p1:Channel>
```

In WCF (.Net Framework) :

```
<ReservationDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.ReservationResponseModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Detail xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.ReservationModel">
        <a:ActionItems xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.CommonModel"/>
        <a:Association>
            <a:ReservationAssociation>
                <a:Requestor xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.CommonModel">
                    <b:ChannelName>NDC</b:ChannelName>
                </a:Requestor>
            </a:ReservationAssociation>
        </a:Association>
        <a:Channel>NDC</a:Channel>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have not customised XMLFormatter in either project . I believe this
> is the way to fix but i cannot understand where i need to go looking

You can add fields of type **XmlSerializerNamespaces** in the three classes `Detail`, `ActionItems` and `Requestor`.

According to your xml structure, I created the following classes(You can modify some different places by yourself.):

```
 public class ReservationDetail
    {
        public Detail Detail { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.ReservationModel")]
    public class Detail
    {
        public ActionItems ActionItems { get; set; }
        public Association Association { get; set; }
        public string Channel { get; set; }
        [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
        public XmlSerializerNamespaces ns;
    }

    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.CommonModel")]
    public class ActionItems
    {
        public string data { get; set; }

        [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
        public XmlSerializerNamespaces ns;
    }
    public class Association
    {
        public ReservationAssociation ReservationAssociation { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReservationAssociation
    {
        public Requestor Requestor { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.CommonModel")]
    public class Requestor
    {
        public string ChannelName { get; set; }

        [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
        public XmlSerializerNamespaces ns;
    }
```

Code:

```
  public IActionResult ReturnXml()
    {
        ReservationDetail request = new ReservationDetail()
        {
            Detail = new Detail()
            {
                ActionItems = new ActionItems() { },
                Channel = "NCC",
                Association = new Association()
                {
                    ReservationAssociation = new ReservationAssociation()
                    {
                        Requestor = new Requestor()
                        {
                            ChannelName = "NCC"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        request.Detail.ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        request.Detail.ns.Add("a", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.ReservationModel");
        request.Detail.ActionItems.ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        request.Detail.ActionItems.ns.Add("b", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.CommonModel");
        request.Detail.Association.ReservationAssociation.Requestor.ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        request.Detail.Association.ReservationAssociation.Requestor.ns.Add("b", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.CommonModel");
        return Ok(request);
    }
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: This step wasnt needed in WCF Service built on top of .Net Framework. Could it be that default serializers are different? This makes it completely manual

Comment: @RahulJha, what's your mean? Does your project is a WCF Service?

Comment: Previously we had a WCF Project in .Net Framework now we are migrating it to ASP.Net Core API. I am thinking the default namespace prefixes generated are different for them because the deefault serializer used in both cases is different? the serializer appends prefixes as a,b,c,d in my WCF Project(older one) and d1p1,d2p1 in ASP.Net Core Web API as a default . I want it to be a,b,c,d in the new one too

Comment: @RahulJha, As you said, the prefix like `d2p1`  is generated by default in core api, if you want to change it, then you can try my method, it will be useful in core api, or you can tell us what code you use of?

Comment: So i want this default behavior changed to use a,b,c,d,... for namespace prefixes instead of d1p1,d2p1,d3p1 and so on when nothing is set for namespaces. And i don't want to manually set it for each class in serialization

Comment: @RahulJha, I think in the core api project, you can only achieve the requirements  manually.

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable to have the alias declarations at the root level (i.e. `<ReservationDetail xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KKR.Service.Presentation.ReservationModel">` etc - which has the same semantics, but isn't quite the same layout) then this can be achieved by supplying a `XmlSerializerNamespaces` object in the `Serialize` call. For example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://foo/foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://bar/bar")]
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
public class Bar
{}
static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        // your aliases and uris here!
        ns.Add("a", "http://foo/foo");
        ns.Add("b", "http://bar/bar");
        var obj = new Foo { Bar = new Bar() };
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, obj, ns);
    }
}
```

which has output:

```xml
<a:Foo xmlns:b="http://bar/bar" xmlns:a="http://foo/foo">
  <b:Bar />
</a:Foo>
```

Comment: I have no access to Model class(dll). But somehow the serializer appends prefixes as a,b,c,d in my WCF Project(older one) and d1p1,d2p1 in ASP.Net Core Web API as a default behavior. I want it to be a,b,c,d in new one too by default